# Where are packages installed in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, debian, packages

I installed postgresql.
sudo apt-get postgresql-9.4
I am not able to find, where it was installed. Where is the data folder of the postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the paths of files installed by a specific package, you can use `dpkg`.  It is installed by default as part of the base system.

```
 dpkg -L postgresql-9.4
```

Will give you an exhaustive list.

Comment: dpkg **has** to be installed - or your system simply isn't Debian or Debian-derived at all ;)

Comment: @flakeshake That would have been my bet but I was covering a base -- will edit (thx).